# What are the possible metrics by which I can assess whether a Java library is suitable to use?

Tags: java, maven

Before starting on a new Java Open Source Framework (e.g. ProjectReactor) or a including a new Open Source Library (e.g. Jackson), I would like to know how popular and stable these dependencies are. In particular I would like to know how many times have these been downloaded. With many maven repositories (Nexus, Artifactory) in play, is there a way to get this information? E.g. if I go to maven central and search for these dependencies, I don't see #downloads?

With JavaScript libraries, this is so much easier. All I need is to go to https://www.npmjs.com and search for the package. It shows the #downloads right there.

If there is no easy way to get #downloads, what are the possible metrics by which I can assess whether a Java library is suitable to use?

**Edit:**
Some people suggested to use "Usages" in the maven central.  But that is the count of how many times this dependency has been used by other maven projects *in the maven central*. IMHO that doesn't always give a good indication about how many times that library was used in enterprise or other non-open-source projects.  Why does maven central not expose #download for everyone? Or maybe there is a way to get this information that I don't know of.

[image]

Comment: Well you can see the [used by](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-core) dependency listing which provides a better view into its popularity than just downloads.

Comment: "*Also, that wouldn't include stats from other repositories*" I mean, realistically there is only Maven Central. If it isn't on there, it's either proprietary or unpopular.

Comment: Maven Central is very often mirrored and cached to minimize traffic.   It is not uncommon for a modern build to need hundreds of megabytes of packages to build from scratch (which a build server by definition need to do).

Comment: That said, my usual "how mature is this project?" approach is to start on the homepage and follow the documentation to the letter and see how far I get.  For some reason the "get new users started" is frequently some of the least maintained bits of the documentation so the matureness show very quickly.

Comment: @Michael - true about Maven Central. I removed that line.

Comment: Not sure why this got closed. Seems fine. "Asking for off-site resource?" maybe... Perhaps it would be better framed as "how can I know whether an OSS Java project is reputable?"

Comment: @Michael true, especially when I said in the disclaimer that this question was turned down in other stackexchange site as well! Do such questions have no place in stack-sites?  Anyways, I like your idea of changing the name, but I am afraid that would make it appear more subjective?

Comment: @Tintin It's true. What makes something reputable is subjective. How about "What are the possible metrics by which I can assess whether a Java library is suitable to use?" That's not subjective. Fundamentally the question you're trying to ask *feels* fine to me. Having to jump through hoops to frame it in a way the satisfies Stack Overflow's criteria feels like a waste of time.

Comment: @Michael I like it, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/) has the number of usages by other projects.

e.g. for [Hamcrest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all)

> Used By   7,059 artifacts

Careful, this website isn't affiliated with Apache. I'm not sure how they get those stats but they probably build the graph themselves.

[This blog post](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/12/now-available-central-download-statistics-for-oss-projects/) states that individual project owners can see download statistics, but I would infer from that that it's *not* public information. The post is 12 years old though so it may have changed since then.

Of course, there's always number of GitHub stars, which is a metric that's applicable for any language.

Comment: I had noticed this usages tab but thought they must be indicative os something else and not the downloads.  For example I searched for apache-commons  (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) and it shows only 4000 usages in Mar 2021!  I would expect this figure to be in 100's of 1000s or maybe in millions for apache-commons! WDYT?

Comment: "has the number of usages by other projects." It's not the number of downloads. It's the number of usages by other projects. Presumably only the projects that mvnrepository has knowledge of.

Comment: @Tintin The stats are skewed. Most things in Maven Central are libraries, rather than full applications. If my corporate application uses Apache Commons, it's not going to appear in that list because we don't publish it to Maven Central. That doesn't mean we're not using it. It's still a good relative indicator of popularity, though.